# How to write a function that returns matrix with random values from a given range in Python?

Tags: python, matrix

I want to write a function that gives as input the dimension of the matrix ( × ) and a range of values (min, max) for possible entries in the matrix and have the return being a corresponding matrix with random values from the value range (return).

How to do that in Python?

Comment: What did try? Please show us youir code.

Comment: Perhaps `numpy.random.randint`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In pure Python, you can use [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) to generate the random values and [a list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to generate the matrix. Example:

```py
from random import randint

m=3
n=4
min_val=1
max_val=10

matrix=[[randint(min_val, max_val) for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]

print(matrix)
```

Example output:

```py
[[1, 2, 2], [1, 6, 7], [5, 9, 7], [2, 4, 10]]
```